# Only last row getting displayed in view in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to fetch certain values from and then pass it to another model in the same control.

However I'm only able to display the last row in the view.

I have shared my code below and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

Controller:

```
public function test($id){
$mapping_details = $this->queue_model->get_mapping_details($id);

foreach ($mapping_details as $value) {
        $data['agent_details'] = array($this->agent_model->get_agent_details($value['user_id']));
    }

  $this->load->view('app/admin_console/agent_queue_mapping_view', $data);
}
```

Model:

```
public function get_agent_details($id) {

    $query = "select * from user_table where id = ".$id." and company_id = ".$this->session->userdata('user_comp_id');

    $res = $this->db->query($query);                       
    return $res->result_array();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow. The problem is the iteration in your controller. You are iterating through the `$mapping_details` results and per every iteration you are re-assigning the value to `$data['agent_details']` , thus losing the last stored information. What you need to do is push to an array, like this:

```
foreach ($mapping_details as $value) {
    $data['agent_details'][] = $this->agent_model->get_agent_details($value['user_id']);
}
```

---

However, wouldn't it be best if you created a query that uses `JOIN` to get the related information from the database? This will be a more efficient way of creating your query, and will stop you from iterating and calling that `get_agent_details()` over and over again. Think of speed. To do this, you would create a **model** method that looks something like this (this is just an example):

```
public function get_mapping_details_with_users($id){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('mapping_details_table as m');
    $this->db->join('user_table as u', 'u.id=m.user_id');
    $this->db->where('m.id', $id);
    $this->db->where('u.company_id', $this->session->userdata('user_comp_id'));
    return $this->db->get()->result();
}
```

Then your **controller** will only need to get that model result and send it to the view:

```
public function test($id){
    $data['details_w_users'] = $this->queue_model->get_mapping_details_with_users($id);
    $this->load->view('app/admin_console/agent_queue_mapping_view', $data);
}
```

---

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: @CodeGodies thanks a lot for your detailed reply. It was so clear. However with your code I'm just getting the first line now. Is something wrong on my side now?

Comment: @Krish thanks. That is an issue. Did you decide to use the JOIN or are you sticking with the way you had it? I guess it would be best for me to take a look at your code. Do you have Teamviewer?

Comment: Works fine. Just modified m.id to m.queue_id for my scenario.

Comment: Nice! Awesome, I'm glad you were able to figure it out and thanks for accepting my answer.